# How to change "Nov 9 03:21:11" to yymmdd mmhhss using AppleScript/Unix?

Tags: applescript, unix

How to change string "Nov 9 03:21:11" to yymmdd mmhhss in AppleScript?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a mac to test with, but the [OSX `date` man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/date.1.html) suggests:

```
old="Nov 9 03:21:11"
new=$( date -j -f "%b %e %T" "$old" "+%Y%m%d %H%M%S" )
echo "$new"
```

I stongly recommend using 4-digit years. Have we learned nothing from Y2K?

Answer (score 0):

Date and time manipulation <strike>in AppleScript</strike> is painful. See [Conversion: String-Date to AppleScript-Date](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=22941) and [Dates & Times in AppleScripts](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=24737) for helpful snippets and an overview of approaches.

The general approach appears to be to hand code the parsing and conversion. For your example:

```
set myStringDate to "Nov 9 03:21:11"

set theMonth to first word of myStringDate
set theDayOfMonth to second word of myStringDate
set theHour to third word of myStringDate
set theMinute to fourth word of myStringDate
set theSecond to fifth word of myStringDate

-- TODO: Add code to convert month to a number
set theConvertedMonth to theMonth

-- Determine the year somehow

set myTransformedDate to "YEAR" & theConvertedMonth & theDayOfMonth & " " & theMinute & theHour & theSecond

-- Be aware of numbers of single digits; you may need to pad with zeros
```

If you are comfortable with the command line, you may find it easier to resort to calling out to a shell script for the conversion.

Comment: Thanks. I'm interested in unix commands but don't know what unix commands i should check out.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and many variations but it fails:

do shell script "date -f \"%b %e %T\" 'Nov  9 12:12:12' \"+%Y%m%d %H%M%S\""

Comment: If `date` is not working for you, expand the AppleScript above. You can always [ask more questions](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) about specific sections you need help with.

Comment: Your `do shell script` is missing the `-j`.  `do shell script "date -j -f \"%b %e %T\" \"Nov 9 12:12:12\" \"+%Y%m%d %H%M%S\""` is what you need.